# Window position will not change sfml c++

Tags: c++, c++17, sfml

My goal right now is to relocate the window to a random location on the desktop. Seems pretty basic and I am probably just making a stupid error but no errors are being thrown but despite that the window doesn't relocate. I am trying to use a class that will return a random vector2i however when I use that the window doesn't relocate.

I define Key not an error but good to know

```cpp
    typedef struct KeySprite {
        sf::Image Img;
        sf::Texture Tex;
        sf::Sprite Sprite;
    }Key;
```

The Random Vector2i

```cpp
    static sf::Vector2i RandSpawn(sf::Image image) 
    {
        cout << "Desktop Demensions:" << sf::VideoMode::getDesktopMode().width << " by " << sf::VideoMode::getDesktopMode().height << endl;
        int RandX = (rand() % sf::VideoMode::getDesktopMode().width) - image.getSize().x;
        int RandY = (rand() % sf::VideoMode::getDesktopMode().height) - image.getSize().y;
        if (RandX < 1 + image.getSize().x)
            RandX = 1 + image.getSize().x;
        if (RandY < 1 + image.getSize().y)
            RandY = 1 + image.getSize().y;
        cout << "Randomly Relocated\n" << RandX << " and " << RandY << endl; // always prints 1 and 1 idk y
        return sf::Vector2i(RandX, RandY);
    }
```

```cpp
   static void DrawKey(string key)
    {

        //Declair Key
        Key Key;
        Key.Img.loadFromFile("Assets/Images/A.png");
        if (key == "A")
            Key.Img.loadFromFile("Assets/Images/A.png");
        else if (key == "D")
            Key.Img.loadFromFile("Assets/Images/D.png");
        else if (key == "E")
            Key.Img.loadFromFile("Assets/Images/E.png");
        else if (key == "Q")
            Key.Img.loadFromFile("Assets/Images/Q.png");
        else if (key == "S")
            Key.Img.loadFromFile("Assets/Images/S.png");
        else if (key == "W")
            Key.Img.loadFromFile("Assets/Images/W.png");
        else if (key == "X")
            Key.Img.loadFromFile("Assets/Images/X.png");
        else if (key == "Z")
            Key.Img.loadFromFile("Assets/Images/Z.png");
        else if (key == "Esc")
            Key.Img.loadFromFile("Assets/Images/esc.png");
        Key.Tex.loadFromImage(Key.Img);
        Key.Sprite.setTexture(Key.Tex);

        //Open Window
        sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(Key.Img.getSize().x, Key.Img.getSize().y, 32), "Key", sf::Style::None);
        window.setPosition(MakeKey::RandSpawn(Key.Img));
        cout << window.getPosition().x << " and " << window.getPosition().y << endl;

        //Make Transparent
        const unsigned char opacity = 1000;
        setTransparency(window.getSystemHandle(), opacity);
        setShape(window.getSystemHandle(), Key.Img);

        //Handle Events
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        //While Open Loop
        while (window.isOpen())
        {
            //MakeTopWindow(window.getSystemHandle());
            cout << "Running While Loop";
            window.clear(sf::Color::Transparent);
            window.draw(Key.Sprite);
            window.display();
        }
    }
```

There are a few other variables that are referenced for making the window slightly transparent but that's not important.
I also call it from the main based of what key is pressed.
Thanks for the help sorry if its a stupid error.

Comment: _"If I use a normal number it does though."_ -- this is a good observation to make. Your next step is to look at the random value you are getting. Try that as a "normal" number and see if that works. (Perhaps your random values are simply out of range?)

Comment: I also tested that by copying the code into main and having it cout them. They were all in range. When i put a cout line straight into the void however it didn't print which leads me to believe that it never ran.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to clean the solution and rebuild it.